# How should query does it work ? ElasticSearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, querydsl, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-java-api

I just want to get all result from a simple Pseudo-SQL query like that:

`[...] WHERE 'idGroups' = '7078' AND ('titre' LIKE '%fuite%' OR 'tag' LIKE '%fuite%' OR 'message' LIKE '%fuite%')`

In done that:

```
        BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("idGroups", 7078))
                .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("titre", "fuite"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("tag", "fuite"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("message", "fuite"));
```

Obviously, that is not returning me desired result .. What's wrong?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
QueryBuilders
            .boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("idGroups", 7078))
            .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("titre", "*fuite*"))
            .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("tag", "*fuite*"))
            .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("message", "*fuite*")).minimumShouldMatch(1);
```

Comment: I tried it, but this isn't working better. For example, if I do that:


`QueryBuilders
            .boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("idGroups", 7078))
            .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("titre", "*fuite*"))`


I have some result with "TEST EVENEMENT - MANDAT" or "Test SDB" as "titre" ..

Comment: This is the same result .. Not really more efficient

Comment: Do you use some plugin like sense or something where you write Elasticsearch Query DSL. Then Try this Query:  `{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"idGroups":{"value":7078}}},{"query_string":{"fields":["titre","tag","message"],"query":"*fuite*"}}]}}}`

Comment: And Please share mapping of your index. `GET /index/type/_mapping`

Comment: So, my war deployement failed and your update hasn't been used. Now, with your update with "minimumShouldMatch", it works better! But, If I execute the request with "fuite", I have a result like "fuite eau" as "titre". When I execute the request with "fuite eau", I have 0 results ..

Comment: Did you try Elasticsearch query. And Please share the mapping.

Comment: Yes sorry, for sure : [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jorisbertomeu/de1f911f3ee6562f6a5347e9803ea4c8)
And the Elastic query doesn't work : `"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [query : {bool={must=[{term={idGroups={value=7078}}}, {query_string={fields=[titre, tag, message], query=*fuite*}}]}}]"`

Comment: The query is working. Why have you added `=` in your query.

Comment: I haven't added any `=` in my query .. [ScreenShot](http://nsa37.casimages.com/img/2017/05/11/17051102563631866.png)

Comment: I'm in the chat :)